# Declaration difference and scope?

Tags: c

In question [Declaration difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31513260/declaration-difference) it was asked what the difference is between

```
int i;

for (i=0; i<100; i++) {
    //some loop....
}
```

and:

```
for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
    //some loop....
}
```

The answers are clear; the 2nd is C99 and the scope of `i` is limited to the loop. I don't have C99 so I can't test and hence ask it as a question: what would be the resolution in the following case:

```
int i = 32;

for (int i=i; i<100; i++) {
    // some loop
}
```

Would the "new" `i` be initialized with the "old" `i`? Or would the old `i` already be inaccessible becaus a new `i` has already been declared?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In this for loop statement

```
int i = 32;

for (int i = i; i < 100; i++) {
    // some loop
}
```

variable `i` declared in the for statement has indeterminate value. The problem is that as soon as a declarator is defined (in this case it consists from identifier `i`) it hides an entity with the same name in the given scope. So in this declaration

```
int i = i;
```

variable i refers to itself in the right side of the `=` .

Another similar example. Let's assume that you have a typedef.

```
typedef int Int;
```

You may write after its definition

```
Int Int;
```

In this case the name `Int` of the object of type `Int` hides the typedef definition and you may not already write

```
Int Another_Int;
```

because the compiler will issue an error.

According to the C Standard (6.2.1 Scopes of identifiers)

> 4 ...If **the declarator** or type specifier that declares the
>   identifier appears inside a block or within the list of parameter
>   declarations in a function definition, the identifier has block scope,
>   which terminates at the end of the associated block.

A more clear is written in the C++ Standard (3.3.2 Point of declaration)

> 1 The point of declaration for a name is immediately after its
>   complete declarator (Clause 8) and before its initializer (if any),
>   except as noted below. [ Example:

```
int x = 12;
{ int x = x; }
```

> Here the second x is initialized with its own (indeterminate) value.
>   —end example ]

Take into account that in this code snippet

```
int i = 10;

{
    int i[i];
}
```

inside the compound statement there is declared array `int i[10];` that is outer variable `i` is used as the array size because inner variable `i` will be declared only when its declarator will be completed.

Comment: Your first example is interesting, because it means a declaration has priority over a definition. The compiler could also have given an error when declaring `Int Int;`

Comment: Your second example is also interesting, and was more or less what I was expecting in my original question: only once the clause is complete, is the new variable called into life (but that is thus not true).

Answer (score 8):

See [C11 6.8.5.3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.5.3): *"If clause-1 is a declaration, the scope of any identifiers it declares is the remainder of the declaration and the entire loop, including the other two expressions".*

The 2nd `i` refers to the `i` being defined, not the old one.

The whole thing is *UB* because you are using the value of `i` (the `i` being defined inside the loop) without a previous assignment (or initialization).

---

*Edit with working (but different) example*

You can still use the old value through the use of a pointer

```
int i = 42;
int *old_i = &i;
for (int i = *old_i; i < 50; i++) printf("%d ", i);
```

Comment: "The whole thing is UB" Because of?

Comment: The whole thing is UB ... because you are using the value of `i` without a previous assignment (or initialization)

Comment: The quote of the standard does not resolve whether the new `i` would be visible after the part `int i` or only when the clause is finished _after_ the initialization `int i=i;`

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: I read the "remainder of the declaration" as the part starting with the `=` => `for (int i /* we are now in the remainder of the declaration */ = i; ...`

Answer (score 5):

No, in any context something like

```
int i=i;
```

is a bad idea, since the second `i` is the same object as the first, and still not initialized.

If you'd insist you could do something like

```
int tmp=i, i=tmp;
```

to have the effect that you want.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Jens Gustedt I've made a few more research and here's what I found: The following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i = 32;

    for (int i=i; i<50; i++) {
        printf("Hello World %d", i); // <-- this is the new i, the other one is not accessible here
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[produce this assembly](https://goo.gl/yz7pz2) with gcc 5.2:

```
.LC0:
    .string "Hello World %d"
main:
    push    rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    sub rsp, 16
    mov DWORD PTR [rbp-8], 32
.L3:
    cmp DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 49
    jg  .L2
    mov eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
    mov esi, eax
    mov edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
    mov eax, 0
    call    printf
    add DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 1
    jmp .L3
.L2:
    mov eax, 0
    leave
    ret
```

The variable used for the loop is `[rbp-4]` which is not initialized and can be whatever. So it's indeed an UB.

Comment: Before `.L3` should have been the initialization of `[rbp-4]` with `[rbp-8]`. It isn't there, so the compiler has clearly used the new `i`. As initializing with itself has no effect, the instructions have been optimized out. Clear & thanks.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I'm glad you raised the question, you allowed me to be less dumb today :)

Comment: Well: the Standard allows an implementation to use the value of the old `i`; but it's still *UB* :-) What I mean is: *using a compiler output as a basis for determining the validity of an expression is not a good way to go about it.*